# Can't get flash content to display in electron application

Tags: flash, electron, ppapi

I have an Electron app running an angular web app within it. We need to show flash content. I previously had this working when my Electron app was running in 64-bit mode on a 64-bit machine.

I am now attempting to run Electron as 32-bit mode on my 64-bit machine. I have the 32-bit flash player installed and am making sure I’m pointing to that version, but it is no longer working. I’m loading a web page within an iframe and the iframe loads the SWF content. But I get this image where the flash content should be displayed.

Using navigator.plugins in the chrome console shows that the plugin has been installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an issue with Electron 7 updating chromium and Chromium in that version has more restricted CORS so Electron will need to update to fix the problem.